# How to watch an instance variable and trigger a method?

Tags: ruby, oop, triggers

```
class Plastic
  MELTING_POINT = 125

  attr_accessor :temperature, :state

  def initialize(room_temp)
    @temperature = room_temp
    @state = :solid
  end

  def inc_temperature
    @temperature += 50
    if @temperature >= Plastic::MELTING_POINT
      self.melt
    end
  end

  def melt
    @state = :liquid
  end
end

class Man
  def apply_heat(obj)
    puts "#{self.class} applies heat onto #{obj.class}"
    obj.inc_temperature 
  end
end

john = Man.new
plastic_piece = Plastic.new(27)

loop do
  john.apply_heat(plastic_piece)
  if plastic_piece.state == :liquid
    puts "plastic_piece just melted at #{plastic_piece.temperature} degress"
    break
  else
    puts "plastic_piece retains shape at #{plastic_piece.temperature} degrees"
  end
end
```

The above ruby code has a `Plastic` class and a `Man` class, An instance of `Man (john)` can apply heat to an instance of `Plastic (plastic piece)`, when heat is applied the temperature of the `plastic_piece` increases and when it goes above its `MELTING_POINT` the `@state` of the plastic piece changes from :solid to `:liquid`.

Here I'm doing the change of `@state` (from :solid to :liquid) manually after increasing the `temperature` within the `increase_temperature` method.

The `increase_temperature` method is actually doing two things which I want to separate out.

I want the `melt` method to be called (by some sort of asynchronous trigger) when the `@temperature` crosses the `MELTLING_POINT`, without manually doing a temperature check. Is this possible?

Comment: There is not a built in way to "watch" variables (e.g. an 'observer'), you would have to make this system yourself. Maybe take some inspiration from ActiveRecord, you could have some central `update` method, and some system for registering callbacks on update

Comment: [This article](https://medium.com/@kopilov.vlad/use-event-emitter-in-ruby-6b289fe2e7b4) may be of interest.

Comment: If the plastic only ever becomes a liquid when it melts at a certain temperature why do you need a second attribute to change it's value? Can't it just be a method that determines melt by the value of temperature?

Answer (score 1):

In the context you've provide, conceptually, `melt` is a verb, but it doesn't actually do anything.  Melting is a side effect of temperature, so you don't magically melt plastic. Physics does that for you. So why not just?

```
class Plastic
  MELTING_POINT = 125

  attr_accessor :temperature, :state

  def initialize(room_temp)
    @temperature = room_temp
  end

  def inc_temperature
    @temperature += 50
  end

  def state
    @temperature >= Plastic::MELTING_POINT ? :liquid : :solid
  end
end
```

Comment: Why can't `state` be a variable which has a value at all times? Here its a method which only calculates & returns the value only when it is called. If there was an animation which would animate the melting process depending on temperature value this wouldn't work. Anyway this is helpful so I'm upvoting it.

Comment: Are you trying to animate something for a terminal app or a web app? If web, you surely would want to do that in javascript, not Ruby. But I don't see why this can't work for animation. In fact, storing state as a separate object would require more computational power than the answer I've provided.  Animation would need to set some kind of threshold for when melting starts, and what the duration would be.  Do you even have this formula?

Comment: I'm not animating anything, that was just a thought that came to my mind.

Comment: Earlier you said and I quote _Melting is a side effect of temperature, so you don't magically melt plastic. Physics does that for you._. Then why am I feeling like I'm the one melting the plastic (by calling state)?. As per your logic some other entity (Physics) should do the melting right?

Comment: I don't know but how does storing state as an object change anything? IMHO it doesn't. It only makes your code more complex  for no apparent reason.   If you need more help, update your question or ask a new one.